# I'm still learning OOP. Any tips on staying unbiased and pragmatic?

Tags: php, oop

I keep reading about defficiencies and issues with languages. Specifically, I'm learning PHP and Javascript, but I see it everywhere. This question arose while reading Javascript: The Good Parts and PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice. While understanding and avoiding easy pitfalls, is there a way I can learn the fundamentals of OOP and discover solid programming practices without overlooking important areas (or simply becoming jaded)?

I'm sure I'll have plenty of opportunity to learn from mistakes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stay unbiased. Pragmatic yes. You want to be biased in your opinions of different languages, that way you know which language/features to use to solve a problem.

I would recommend for OOP that you follow [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)). Another reference would be [Pragmatic Programmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_Programmers). My personal preference for writing code is [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

Just remember, don't be afraid to be a beginner and learn something new. Just yesterday on SO I put my opinion out there in comments and learned something very valuable concerning deployment of libraries.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the good references.

Comment: Your welcome. Remember programming is a rabbit hole. There's no turning back.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you learn C if you haven't already. It is essintial to learn the basics of pointers and memory management to really understand what you're doing. I made the mistake of learning C later and my work suffered for it.

Secondly, there are many languages considered to be very good at object-orientation.

I'd reccomend: [Ruby](http://ruby-lang.org/) and [Go](http://www.golang.org/)

Comment: It's good to know about pointers, but that knowledge definitely isn't necessary for writing in PHP. I don't think the answer to this question is to "learn three new languages". For PHP, the specifics of memory management definitely takes a backseat to design patterns. I'm out of downvotes for the day, though.

Comment: I may just be stupid, I don't see how any of your first paragraph is useful for learning good OOP practices. C is not remotely OO and neither pointers nor C's memory management have anything to do with OO.

Comment: why don't you have him learn Common Lisp. You can get the best of all worlds.